# $f \in c^\infty: f(x, y) = 0$ only at the origin. What happens with the gradient?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have a function $f \in c^n$ such that:

- $f(0, 0) = 0$
- $f(x,y) \neq 0 (\forall (x,y) \neq (0,0))$

I want to prove that the parcial derivatives at the origin are both 0. The thing is that I'm stuck with these limits:

- $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t,0)}{t}$
- $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(0,t)}{t}$

How can I solve those indeterminations?

It is valid to state that since $f$ has continuous derivatives, both can't go to infinity and therefore those limits go to 0?

Comment: You want to assume the partial derivative is nonzero, then reach a contradiction.  [PS: It would help to define your notation $c^n$, for example, we do not know what $n$ means.]

Comment: You can use the implicit/inverse function theorem. If it isn't the case $\nabla f=0$, then prove that $f$ changes signs in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Would it work to apply the Implicit Function Theorem and state that the implicit function $\phi(x)$ is defined for only one point and then it would contradict the fact that it is differentiable?

Comment: Alternatively, the argument could be that the I.F.T guarantees there are **open sets**, which in this case is false since both only contain $0$.

Comment: @John Can you solve the one dimensional version of this problem? If you can, what keeps you from adapting the solution to $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Would the one dimensional version use the fact that $x=0$ is the only place where $y=g(x)$ can change signs?